# Send an email after n number of events in Log4net

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I have a Log4Net appender that sends an email for every error.
I want it to send the email after some number of events, and have all the events in the one email.

Is that possible in log4net?

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender,log4net">
    <to value="" />
    <from value="" />
    <subject value="Error email" />
    <smtphost value="" />
    <bufferSize value=""/>
    <lossy value="true"/>
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator,log4net">
        <threshold value="ERROR"/>
    </evaluator>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <conversionpattern value="%property{log4net:HostName} :: %level :: %message %newlineLogger: %logger%newlineThread: %thread%newlineDate: %date%newlineNDC: %property{NDC}%newline%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: There's nothing built in that I know of, but check out [this post](http://andrewchaa.me.uk/2013/01/07/sending-errors-in-a-roll-up-digest-email-with-log4net/) on extending `SmtpAppender`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `bufferSize` attribute to receive an email grouping n events directly in your email. This already exists in the `SmtpAppender`.

If you want more control on what the log sends you (for example all x events previous to an error) you can use a [`BufferingForwardingAppender`](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-8-Lossy-Logging.aspx) with your desired buffer size and a lossy attitude: plug its output into you email appender and you will receive errors in context. This lets you receive errors in context only if needed.

Please note that the smtp appender has the lossy attribute directly, you can used the technique in the link directly if you don't need more control on how logging happens